# Missing redirect_uri error for Resource owner password credentials grant type

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am trying to write a script on Python that fetches my friend list from facebook. To fetch data, I need to get the access token. I am using requests_oauthlib package to achieve the same. Since I am not writing a web application, I have not used local webserver(no redirect url). I choose to use Resource owner password credentials grant type. I am getting error.

This is my code:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import LegacyApplicationClient

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '**********'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = '*********'
username = 'Aman Mittal'
password = '****'
token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"

oauth = OAuth2Session(client=LegacyApplicationClient(client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID))
oauth_access_token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,username=username, password=password, client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID)
```

When I run the script, it shows error - 'Missing access token parameter'

I went through traceback and realized that access token received is this:

```
{"error":{"message":"Missing redirect_uri parameter.","type":"OAuthException","code":191,"fbtrace_id":"CUSmQKT8YGb"}}
```

First of all, I don't understand while using Legacy Application client(Resource Owner password credentials grant type ), why do I need redirect uri?

If I do choose to start a webserver alongside using web.py or something else. How do I register it on Facebook? or Do I even need to?

PS.  I am new to both Python and posting on Stack Overflow. Please try to explain with details and forgive me if I have committed any stupid mistake.

Comment: You can't. The user have to interactively login.

Comment: I am already logged into my account, If you are talking about that, which I think you are not.
We use redirect uri to direct end-user to client after getting authorization from it. But I don't need to authorize when I already have its password. I can simply ask for access token. Then why interactively?

Comment: You need a redirect url. In the browser the user will be redirected to Facebook and then redirected back to the url you set. That is the interactive part.

Comment: But process you are explaining is required if I am asking for authorization code, right? not if I have password credentials
Are you talking about when I am directing to token endpoint?
Please explain in detail.

Comment: You can't login using username and password using the API. You have to redirect the user to Facebook. Just read Facebook's documentation

Comment: This method is not allowed with facebook. Okay. Only way is to ask for authorization code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook does not support the OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type.

Comment: So no way to do without web server.. huh?

Comment: not sure about that comment: no way to do without a browser would be a better description